# Is there an equivalent code to tsset and tsfill in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, stata

I am wondering if there is an equivalent code in Python which offers the same functionality of `tsset`and `tsfill, full` in Stata.

From the Stata manual, the description of `tsset` is as follows:

`tsset` declares the data in memory to be a time series

From the Stata manual, the description of `tsfill, full`is as follows:

`tsfill` is used after `tsset` to fill in gaps in time-series data and gaps in panel data with
new observations, which contain missing values. For instance, perhaps observations for `timevar` =
1, 3, 5, 6, . . . , 22 exist. `tsfill` would create observations for `timevar` = 2 and `timevar` = 4 containing all missing values.

Example data:

```
data = {'date': ['2014-05-01','2014-05-01','2014-05-01','2014-05-01',
         '2014-05-02','2014-05-02','2014-05-02','2014-05-03',
         '2014-05-03','2014-05-03'],'id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 1,
         2, 3, 1, 2, 4],'obs': [10, 5, 7, 3, 2,4, 3, 8, 6, 11]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'id','obs'])
df.index = df1['date']
del df['date']

df

            id  obs
date               
2014-05-01   1   10
2014-05-01   2    5
2014-05-01   3    7
2014-05-01   4    3
2014-05-02   1    2
2014-05-02   2    4
2014-05-02   3    3
2014-05-03   1    8
2014-05-03   2    6
2014-05-03   4   11
```

In Stata, you would use `tsset id date` to declare the data to be time series, then you would use `tsfill, full` to transform the data into the following:

`id` 4 at `date` 2014-05-02 and `id` 3 at `date` 2014-05-03 now appear in the dataframe

```
           id  obs
date               
2014-05-01   1   10
2014-05-01   2    5
2014-05-01   3    7
2014-05-01   4    3
2014-05-02   1    2
2014-05-02   2    4
2014-05-02   3    3
2014-05-02   4    .
2014-05-03   1    8
2014-05-03   2    6
2014-05-03   3    .
2014-05-03   4    11
```

Is there an equivalent code in Python to execute the same output that Stata does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
data = {'date': ['2014-05-01','2014-05-01','2014-05-01','2014-05-01',
         '2014-05-02','2014-05-02','2014-05-02','2014-05-03',
         '2014-05-03','2014-05-03'],'id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 1,
         2, 3, 1, 2, 4],'obs': [10, 5, 7, 3, 2,4, 3, 8, 6, 11]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'id','obs'])

result = df.set_index(['id','date']).unstack(fill_value='.').stack().sort_index(level=1).reset_index()  
result = result.set_index('date')

In [1]: result
Out[1]: 
            id obs
date              
2014-05-01   1  10
2014-05-01   2   5
2014-05-01   3   7
2014-05-01   4   3
2014-05-02   1   2
2014-05-02   2   4
2014-05-02   3   3
2014-05-02   4   .
2014-05-03   1   8
2014-05-03   2   6
2014-05-03   3   .
2014-05-03   4  11
```

Comment: I have been finding this solution for almost one day. This solution is super helpful!